# Jenkins as Service Keeps Losing Elevated Privileges

Tags: jenkins

We recently tried moving our Windows Jenkins slaves to run as a service instead of just running the slave agent jnlp file.

According to the Mercurial Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin),

```
The default installation runs windows service with "local system" account, which does not seem to have enough priveleges for hg to execute, so You could try running Jenkins service with the same account as TortoiseHG, which will allow it to complete.
```

This we did, and it worked.  For a while.

But sometimes after there was a disconnect between the Jenkins slave and master, it would stop working.  Jenkins would call mercurial and it would hang, just like it would do if the service was running with the "local system" account.

I could sometimes get it to start working again by restarting the Jenkins service on the slave.  But somtimes I'd have to go back in and re-set the service to run with an elevated account.

Has anybody else experienced anything like this?  Is there any way to keep the Jenkins Service running with elevated priveleges?

Comment: If you have created it as a service, you can go to the services list (win+R -> services.msc) select it and inform an account with administrator privileges on Log On tab. Try that.

Comment: That is how I set it up to have administrator privileges.  The problem is that those privileges don't seem to *stick*.